# what's the difference between NSCachesDirectory and NSDownloadsDirectory in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to save downloaded magazines to one directory in my iOS app. It seems  `NSCachesDirectory` and `NSDownloadsDirectory` are suitable. I don't know the difference between them and which one is suitable for downloading magazines. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NSCachesDirectory can be deleted in cases of low memory

If you don't want your files to be deleted you have to store them in the Documents directory, but add "do not backup" if you don't want your files to be backed by iTunes, iCloud etc..

Please look at the apple's [File System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW2) or [File System Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW1)

Comment: can you give some simple description?

Comment: FYI, `NSCachesDirectory` isn't mentioned anywhere in the linked article anymore.

Comment: This answer is too vague IMO. "NSCachesDirectory can be deleted in cases of low memory" - maybe if you mean low *disk/persistent* memory.

Answer (score 3):

i would prefer  NSCachesDirectory or temp directory to save files, because for NSDownloadsDirectory or document directory, you have to use don't back up or iCloud for greater than iOS 5. because iOS 5.0 does not allow to save any data in document directory , it is a major reason to rejection of app store.

Comment: "iOS 5.0 does not allow to save any data in document directory , it is a major reason to rejection of app store" : Can you give any Proof ?

Comment: please refer follow link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209406/ios-5-does-not-allow-to-store-downloaded-data-in-documents-directory